# how to make http request to google tag manager with dataLayer?

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

I have the following line of code, which is basically the google tag manager script:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="ltr">
<head>
<!-- Google Tag Manager -->
<script>
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
    j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
    'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
    })(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-M3WNDLC');</script>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <title>Test Page</title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

What I do next is:

1. Paste that code onto any HTML page
2. Open up developer tools.
3. Go to Networks tab and clear everything else so I don't confuse myself with the upcoming HTTP requests I'm about to make
4. Go to the javascript console
5. Typed in `window.dataLayer.push({food:"pizza",event:"pageview"})` then pressed enter
6. I type `window.dataLayer` to inspect it's contents, and confirmed it has the new item from step 5.
7. I go to the Networks tab in my developer console and note that **no http request was made to google tag manager servers**

So my question is, how do I transmit my new `window.dataLayer` element to google tag manager?  Is the `window.dataLayer` supposed to be an observable?  And GTM has some observers that will fire off functionality when the state of `window.dataLayer` has changed?

Comment: Looking at the docs, the `window` might be extraneous. https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/devguide#renaming. `dataLayer.push()` should be sufficient

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the current incarnation, Google Tag Manager is a purely client side technology. The only function of the GUI is to configure that tags that are then bundled with some boilerplate Javascript (a selector engine, and the logic to evaluate conditions for triggers and values for variables). This file is then downloaded by the browser, and from then on there is no interaction with the GTM server.

All your example does is to add a value to the dataLayer array. While GTM augments the push method for the dataLayer array with some extra logic, this is at the core still just a way to add a value to an array, no server interaction necessary. You will only get http requests if you have a tag configured that interacts with a server.

Apparently Google is working on a server-side solution for tag management (something similar to segment.com I presume) that will live on a VM in the Google Cloud, and at that point the idea of sending http requests to GTM might make sense. For now, GTM is a it of Javascript that already lives in the browser, so no http requests are required to communicate with GTM.

Comment: ugh....I've been reading a bunch of blogs, and so many authors claim `window.dataLayer.push(...data...)` is superior to `window.dataLayer = [..data...]` because the former can be declared before or after the declaration of the google tag manager boiler script where as the latter should only be defined before the google tag manager boiler script.  This completely mislead me to think `dataLayer` is an observable, and there are observers that will fire off `httprequests` every time the state changes.  So frustrated...lost so much time.

Comment: Ah, I think I know where the misunderstand is. GTM amends the push method with a method that scans the pushed objects for a key with the name "event". When it finds the "event" key the internal variables are updated and the pushed values are made available to the internal state of GTM for the use as variables. In that sense there is an "observer" in the code, but this is still a purely client side process.